# use jquery to insert html code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am new to jquery and html. I am trying to insert code that is in jquery into the class="content" in the html code I check the console and it reaches the loadDoc() function. I tried this with .html and .append both did not work.

html code

```
    <section id="doc" class="main">
       <div class="content">
       </div>
    </section>
```

Jquery code

```
    function loadDoc(){
       console.log("Load Doc");
       var content = '<header>This is the header</header><article>' +
       '<p>This is the content form loadDoc() </p></article>';
       $( "section#doc.content" ).append( content );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `#doc .content` instead of `section#doc.content` since your goal is to insert html into the `.content` element located in the `#doc` element.

```
function laodDoc(){
   console.log("Load Doc");
   var content = '<header>This is the header</header><article>' +
   '<p>This is the content form loadDoc() </p></article>';
   $( "#doc .content" ).append( content );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery selector is incorrect. Instead of

```
$( "section#doc.content" )
```

you need to have

```
$( "section#doc .content" )
```

This is because the `.content` element is inside of `section#doc`.

Comment: i was quickly rewriting it should be loadDoc() in question my apologies

Comment: @user3464613 Got it. See the second part of my answer that I edited in - you've got an error in your jQuery selector as well.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$( "#doc .content" ).html( content );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery and a much simpler code:

```
var content = '<header>This is the header</header><article>' +
       '<p>This is the content form loadDoc() </p></article>';
$(".content").html(content);
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9oneuqf9/

Comment: They might not want to update every single class called `content`.

Comment: ok, in that case there can be an extended selector "section #doc.content"

Comment: my bad typing too fast... Correct syntax: "section#doc .content" Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9oneuqf9/1/